# Maple - Substituting into equation

Tags: function, substitution, maple

I am having difficulty setting up a function where I substitute `x1[1]` and `x2[1]` into it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
 restart;
 with(LinearAlgebra);
 x1[1] := -2+1606*alpha;
 x2[1] := 2+400*alpha;
 f := proc (alpha) options operator, arrow; (-x1[1]^2+1)^2+100*(-x1[1]^2+x2[1])^2 end proc;
```

The output from f leaves `x1[1]` and `x2[1]` and does not replace them with `-2+1600*alpha` and `2+400*alpha` as desired.

`f(0);` then does not give the desired output of 409.

I can physically substitute `-2+1606*alpha` and `2+400*alpha` in myself as shown by the function `g` below.  Though this is not what I would like as I would like it to take whatever `x1[1]` and `x2[1]` are set to, and not do it manually.

```
g := proc (alpha) options operator, arrow; (1-(1606*alpha-2)^2)^2+100*(2+400*alpha-(1606*alpha-2)^2)^2 end proc
g(0);
```

Here `g(0);` gives 409 as desired.

I have attached a photo below of how the maple output appears on my screen.

[image]

Comment: Hi Student201. I like your question. It's well thought out and appropriately doesn't leave anything to the reader's imagination. One note though: you can format inline code with backticks (`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the operator procedure on an expression, Maple does that *before* evaluation. In the expression

```
 f := proc (alpha) options operator, arrow; (-x1[1]^2+1)^2+100*(-x1[1]^2+x2[1])^2 end proc;
```

which is the same as using the "arrow" notation

```
 f2 := alpha -> (-x1[1]^2+1)^2+100*(-x1[1]^2+x2[1])^2;
```

then Maple is looking for any `alpha`. There is none. When you then call `f(0)`, the expression is evaluated with the (non-existing) `alpha` from the call of the operator. Thus, `f(x) = f(0)` for any `x`. [From the help page](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=option):

> The use of option arrow also disables Maple simplification rules that add any non-local names in the operator expression to the parameter list. This option has no meaning for modules.

Instead, what you can do is use the [`unapply`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=unapply) operator, which returns an operator of an *evaluated* expression. This becomes a little more clear if you define a variable `expr` as your function content.

```
expr := (-x1[1]^2+1)^2+100*(-x1[1]^2+x2[1])^2;

f := alpha -> expr;
h := unapply(expr, alpha);

h(0); # returns 409
```